# jump to files on puppet include function

Tags: movement

On a particular init.pp file, I have the following definition:

```
class temp_executor {
  if $::fqdn =~ /host.*01/ {
    include ::temp_executor::deploy
  }
}
```

`deploy.pp` is on the same folder as `init.pp`.

I want to jump to that deploy.pp file, while highlighting `::temp_executor::deploy` by pressing `gf` or `gd` or something similar.

Currently I have to look for the file by name, and while using `fzf` is quick, it's not as good as jumping.

I've installed the rails-vim plugin (https://vimawesome.com/plugin/rails-vim) but I don't know how to go about this particular movement.

Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT:**

To clarify, `temp_executor` is the name of the module in puppet, and `deploy.pp` is the name of the manifest on that module's folder.

So the structure is like this:

```
temp_executor
│   
└───manifests
│   │   deploy.pp
│   │   init.pp
│   
└───files
│   │   (...)
│
│
(...)
```

The expected behavior for me would be to highlight the word deploy the line `include ::temp_executor::deploy` and jump to the file `deploy.pp`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don’t think this has anything to do with rails. Rather, you need to set the include, includeexpr, and maybe suffixesadd options for the filetype you’re working with. Then gf should work fine.

Comment: You may also need to set path

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think we made the same mistake: the OP wants to jump to a definition in another file, not to the file under the cursor. `tags` and/or `LSP` might be the way to go.

Comment: @Biggybi i’m not sure—the questions says jump to deploy.pp .. OP, can you [edit] to clarify ?

Comment: The suffixesadd did it, thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works when your cursor is on the file name, `deploy.pp` in your example.

```
:setlocal suffixesadd=.pp
```

`'suffixesadd'` is the option responsible for the filenames tested when you try to jump with `gf`, and other commands.

When you input the above command, `temp_executor.pp` will be tested by `gf`.

You can drop the command in a `ftplugin` file. Or you could put something like this in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup Suffixepp
  au!
  au FileType pp setlocal suffixesadd=.pp
augroup END
```

You'll also need to set the `path`, unless both files are in the current working directory. `gf` will only try the folders listed by `path`.

Finally, depending on your language, you may need to set a proper `includeexpr`, to use the `include` as an actual filename.

Useful doc:

- `:h 'suffixesadd'`
- `:h 'path'`
- `:h 'include'`
- `:h 'includeexpr'`

Comment: Why delete? I do think youre missing includeexpr at the least, but it’s a good start

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I never used `includeexpr`, but in the case where both files are in the same directory, is it necessary?

Comment: It can be when the import syntax isn’t file-based (eg, java and python use ., and rust uses ::, instead of /, so you want to translate those first)

Comment: Using the command you mentioned `:setlocal suffixesadd=pp` when editing the file, I still get "Can't find "deploy" in path", so it doesn't look like it's adding it to the suffixes? I'm using VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 on mac os x, if that's relevant.

Comment: @pr3c0g Ugh, I missed a dot : it's `.pp`. I cleaned the answer with an edit. Hope it works now!

Comment: Oh wow, I missed it, my bad. Well that does it, thanks a lot for that! This is awesome and will save me much time :)

Comment: @pr3c0g *My* bad, I insist. I edited the post after your last comment. I'm glad it helped!